# Store Complex JSON objects in Local Database Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite, persistent-storage, flutter-moor

How can we store an nested JSON object in SQLite database. In Android Room we used to have **Embedded** and **Relation** to store and retrieve complex data objects. But in flutter how can we achieve the same?
I tried exploring [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor), and [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor). But none seem to help except for Moor, which allows us Map the values to Object using Joins. something like below code.

```
  Stream<List<TaskWithTag>> watchAllTasks() {
return (select(tasks)
      ..orderBy(
        [
          (t) =>
              OrderingTerm(expression: t.dueDate, mode: OrderingMode.desc),
          (t) => OrderingTerm(expression: t.name),
        ],
      ))
    .join(
      [
        leftOuterJoin(tags, tags.name.equalsExp(tasks.tagName)),
      ],
    )
    .watch()
    .map((rows) => rows.map(
          (row) {
            return TaskWithTag(
              task: row.readTable(tasks),
              tag: row.readTable(tags),
            );
          },
        ).toList());
```

}

So What exactly is the right way to do this?

Comment: What are you finding lacking with what you've tried?

Comment: I am looking for alternative way to implement this. In Moor I cannot reuse my Tables class for API request/response models. Since the table creation format in Moor is different. I know we can create tables with .moor file, but this result in more code. I am looking for optimized way to implement this.